# Minor change in subtitle file using regex

Tags: regex

I was downloading subtitles for Two and a Half Men. Then I got two subtitles for two episodes. One of which is working using VLC media player and one is not working. To see what's wrong, I opened both files using Gedit and saw a minor difference which is probably the reason.

**Working sub :**

```
1
00:00:02,412 --> 00:00:04,363
- So, dear...
- What?

2
00:00:04,574 --> 00:00:06,359
Do you see anything you like?

3
00:00:06,653 --> 00:00:08,887
I don't know. What's venison?
```

**Non-working sub:**

```
1
00:00:02:640 --> 00:00:05:160
Well, this is gonna be
a sucky weekend.

2
00:00:05:440 --> 00:00:09:720
Try spending it with an 11 -year-old
who does nothing but complain.

3
00:00:10:280 --> 00:00:12:080
You mean me?
```

**Difference:**

As you can see the only difference is the comma used in the timestamp.

`00:00:02,412 --> 00:00:04,363` vs `00:00:02:640 --> 00:00:05:160`

I tried to replace the colon with comma and it worked well. So my question is whether this can be done using a regex string replacement ? If yes then how.

Comment: Anything. Like any editor supporting regex.

Comment: use notepad++ editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using *Positive Lookbehind* and *Positive Lookahead* to match all the invalid colon and now simply replace it with comma.

```
(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):(?=\d+)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/eJ7dN6/1)

There is no need of any editor. Simply copy it from the demo.

---

In [Notepadd++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Find what:    `(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}):(?=\d+)`
Replace with:  `,`

Don't forget to check the regular expression radio button.

Comment: Do we really need a photo of editor, like seriously? And worse, from Windows, which looks like XP? This is just plain GROSS.

Comment: @MightyPork OK I have removed the photo that is not so decorated and stylish. :)

Comment: @MightyPork there is no need of any editor, I forget that that I have already mentioned the demo site. Simply copy it from there.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps like this:

```
(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),(\d{3})
```

Replace with

```
\1:\2
```

In case your editor uses dollar for backreference, use `$1:$2`.

Comment: Depending on your language or tool, you may need `$1:$2` instead.